# Intel Driver Manager Error "Package libdrm2:i386 cannot be removed"

Tags: 13.04, graphics, video, intel

I recently fresh-installed ubuntu 13.04. Running on Asus u43f

After running system test, my video test failed.

I have installed the latest version of Intel Driver Manager. While running this to update my drivers, it fails and the following message is displayed:

"Package libdrm2:i386 cannot be removed"
The terminal output during this process is:

```
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('AllowUnauthenticated', <true>)
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-authenticating'>)
 update_action
 Authenticating : Done  [ 100 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Progress', <9>)
 update_progress
 Authenticating : Done  [   9 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-resolving-dep'>)
 update_action
 Resolving dep : Done  [   9 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-loading-cache'>)
 update_action
 Loading cache : Done  [   9 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Dependencies', <(['fakeroot=1.18.4-2ubuntu1', 'debhelper=9.20120909ubuntu1', 'libalgorithm-merge-perl=0.08-2', 'g++-4.7=4.7.3-1ubuntu1', 'dh-apparmor=2.8.0-0ubuntu11', 'libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl=0.04-2build3', 'po-debconf=1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1', 'g++=4:4.7.3-1ubuntu10', 'dkms=2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu2', 'build-essential=11.6ubuntu4', 'dpkg-dev=1.16.10ubuntu1', 'html2text=1.3.2a-15ubuntu3', 'libalgorithm-diff-perl=1.19.02-3', 'libstdc++6-4.7-dev=4.7.3-1ubuntu1', 'libmail-sendmail-perl=0.79.16-1', 'libsys-hostname-long-perl=1.4-2'], @as [], ['libdrm-nouveau2:i386=2.4.43-0ubuntu1.1', 'libdrm-radeon1:i386=2.4.43-0ubuntu1.1', 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386=9.1.3-0ubuntu0.3', 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386=9.1.3-0ubuntu0.3', 'libdrm2:i386=2.4.43-0ubuntu1.1', 'libdrm-intel1:i386=2.4.43-0ubuntu1.1'], @as [], ['libdrm-nouveau2=2.4.45-0ubuntu1', 'libdrm-radeon1=2.4.45-0ubuntu1', 'xserver-xorg-video-intel=2:2.21.9-0ubuntu0~raring', 'libdrm2=2.4.45-0ubuntu1', 'libdrm-intel1=2.4.45-0ubuntu1', 'libva1=1.2.1-0ubuntu0~raring'], @as [], @as [])>)
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Download', <int64 14502010>)
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Space', <int64 25445376>)
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Unauthenticated', <['i915-3.9-3.8-dkms', 'i965-va-driver', 'libdrm-intel1', 'libdrm-nouveau2', 'libdrm-radeon1', 'libdrm2', 'libkms1', 'libva-drm1', 'libva-egl1', 'libva-glx1', 'libva-intel-vaapi-driver', 'libva-tpi1', 'libva-wayland1', 'libva-x11-1', 'libva1', 'vainfo', 'xserver-xorg-video-intel']>)
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('HighTrustWhitelistedPackages', <@as []>)
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-setting-up'>)
 update_action
 Setting up : Done  [   9 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-waiting'>)
 update_action
 Waiting : Done  [   9 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/run_transaction_finished: APT transaction finished
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-running'>)
 update_action
 Running : Done  [   9 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Progress', <11>)
 update_progress
 Running : Done  [  11 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Error', <('error-not-remove-essential', 'Package libdrm2:i386 cannot be removed')>)
transaction-view.c/on_pm_op_failed: Package manager operation failed: Package libdrm2:i386 cannot be removed
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('Status', <'status-finished'>)
 update_action
 Finished : Done  [  11 % ] ⏲
package-manager-ubuntu.c/on_transaction_signal: Received transaction signal PropertyChanged from :1.105 with ('ExitState', <'exit-failed'>)
 on_transaction_signal
 Finished : Done  [  11 % ] ◦
```

Comment: Please don't add solution into the body of the question. Instead, answer your question (I did it because you didn't for a long time) and mark it as accepted. This is the way how does the site work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (credits to the OP):

Ok here is what I did to fix this.

I wanted to upgrade all my packages with the `sudo` command. I couldn't do that because the PPA Wasn't keyed right for the download.01.org package. So looking on the website, they offered the following:

Signatures - Ubuntu*

In order to "trust" the Intel® Linux Graphics Installer, you will need to add keys to Ubuntu's software package manager ("apt"). Open a terminal, and execute these line:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -

wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

Now, to update the packages. So

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now that we have the updates, we upgrade

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now that probably did it, but we want to be sure. So I ran the Intel Graphics Drivers Manager. This time, it worked.